# Is that possible for Linux and windows machines to be infected with KeRanger ransomware?

Tags: windows, malware, linux, macos, ransomware

According to [theguardian](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/mar/07/apple-targeted-by-keranger-ransom-malware-for-first-time) The Transmission site offers the open source software that was infected with the ransomware called KeRanger malware, it's programmed to encrypt files on an infected personal computer then the hackers will asks users to pay ransoms.
Is that possible for windows and linux users to be affected by KeRanger after using Transmission client?

Comment: The issue was/has only been discovered in the OS X installer. http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/03/new-os-x-ransomware-keranger-infected-transmission-bittorrent-client-installer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it's hard to say this because it's a new kind of ransomware.

Ransomware isn't currently spreading to other computers, it only stays on the infected computer.